# Joining a table on itself with aggregation

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, self-join

I am trying to (efficiently) fetch rows from the connections table, where the startdate is the latest within cpid - for selected cpid's.

Here's an example of the data in the connections table with rows I want marked with <<<

```
connid   cpid  startdate
1        20    7/17/16
2        20    8/23/16
3        20    9/12/16 <<<
4        30    6/17/16
5        30    8/23/16 <<<
6        40    2/24/16
7        40    3/17/16
8        40    5/18/16 <<<
etc...
```

This query returns the latest startdate and cpid, but I'm not sure how to join it with itself to get the result that I need:

```
select cpid, max(startdate)
from connections
where cpid in (  
20,
30,
40
)
group by cpid
```

The result I'm looking for is as follows:

```
connid   cpid  startdate
3        20    9/12/16
5        30    8/23/16
8        40    5/18/16
```

Any help would be appreciated!
robm

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Something like this:

```
WITH Numbered AS
(
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY cpid ORDER BY startdate DESC) AS Nr
          ,*
    FROM connections
)
SELECT *
FROM Numbered
WHERE Nr=1;
```

The function `ROW_NUMBER()` will add a running number to the row. `PARTITION BY` allows you to re-start the running number for groups and `ORDER BY` allows you to define the order for the numbering. With `DESC` you will get the latest on top, hence  Nr=1.

### UPDATE: old-fashioned...

If you need this on other systems than SQL-Server you might go the *old-fashioned* way:

```
SET DATEFORMAT mdy;
DECLARE @tbl TABLE(connid INT,  cpid INT,  startdate DATE);
INSERT INTO @tbl VALUES
( 1,20,'7/17/16')
,(2,20,'8/23/16')
,(3,20,'9/12/16')
,(4,30,'6/17/16')
,(5,30,'8/23/16')
,(6,40,'2/24/16')
,(7,40,'3/17/16')
,(8,40,'5/18/16') ;

SELECT * 
FROM @tbl AS tbl
WHERE tbl.startdate IN(SELECT MAX(x.startdate) FROM @tbl AS x WHERE x.cpid=tbl.cpid)
```

Comment: Wow - that was a quick response - thanks! Let me give it a try and get back to you. BTW, how portable is this SQL? We're in the process of migrating from SS to PG...

Comment: @robm See my update (btw: The ROW_NUMBER() was wrongly grouping by `connid`, changed this to `cpid`)

Comment: I get too many results. Where do i restrict the result set to matching cpid's per my query above?

Comment: No worries - I just needed to change `partition by connid` to `partition by cpid`! Many thanks.

Comment: - I'm a noob at this. Done! :-)

Answer (score 1):

Here's an alternative solution using CROSS APPLY rather than a CTE, the execution plan is different, once you try it on your environment it could be more efficient.

```
DROP TABLE #connections
CREATE TABLE #connections(connid INT, cpid INT,startdate datetime)

INSERT INTO  #connections(connid,cpid,startdate)
VALUES
(1,'20','20160717')
,(2,'20','20160823')
,(3,'20','20160912')
,(4,'30','20160617')
,(5,'30','20160823')
,(6,'40','20160224')
,(7,'40','20160317')
,(8,'40','20160518')

SELECT 
    c.connid,c.cpid,c.startdate
FROM
#connections c
CROSS APPLY (
    SELECT
        cpid
        ,MAX(startdate) startdate
    FROM
        #connections
    GROUP BY
        cpid
    ) a
WHERE
    c.cpid = a.cpid
    AND c.startdate = a.startdate
```

Comment: I like the idea (+1 from my side). With an index on `startdate` both approaches should perform fairly well...

Comment: @pacreely: Thanks for the tip. I'll check out the execution plans.

Comment: @Shnugo - There is no index on startdate. Any idea which is then is better?

Comment: @robm Why not create one? If you need this more often, this will - for sure! - be worth it... If this is a *one-time-action*, performance should not matter that much...

Comment: does your table contain just 3 columns or is it more than you've included in the original question?